"Removed use of the USE_EXACT_ALARM permission from all version codes in the submission. This includes production and test tracks."
Did anyone manage to solve this?
I've had my app stopped for a month.
I already removed it, I also added "SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM", nothing helped. And my app doesn't even have an "alarm" affinity...
I have already deleted previous versions on Google, I used "SCHEDULE" which Google recommends.
I already sent a version with just "SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM".
A version with nothing.
Nothing solved it, it always gives the same error.

How you resolve this? I have the same issue.
